# Unable to install OpenGL/GLUT libraries

Tags: 14.04, command-line, dependencies, opengl, development

I'm trying to install OpenGL/GLUT libraries but I always get this error. Can someone help me?

I tryed to install il using the command **sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev**

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 freeglut3-dev : Depends: libgl1-mesa-dev but it is not going to be installed or
                          libgl-dev
                 Depends: libglu1-mesa-dev but it is not going to be installed or
                          libglu-dev
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

*Update*, I tried to solve installing **sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-dev** but I get

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-dev : Depends: mesa-common-dev (= 11.2.0-1ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx (= 11.2.0-1ubuntu2) but 11.2.0-1ubuntu2.2 is to be installed
                   Depends: libdrm-dev (>= 2.4.65) but it is not going to be installed
```

My fear is that this is a recursive problem, can I solve it in a simple way?

**Update** result of **sudo apt install -f**

```
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Your install command is missing in your question. Please edit. .... Did you forget `sudo apt update` ?

Comment: @Knud Larsen I did It before

Comment: »» you have held broken packages «« : `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: @KnudLarsen Just done but I get
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
And obliviously the same problems

Comment: Question edited!! @KnudLarsen

Comment: `{mesa-common-dev (=11.2.0-1ubuntu2), libgl1-mesa-glx( 11.2.0-1ubuntu2)}` are Ubuntu 16.04 packages. ... `libdrm-dev (>= 2.4.65)` : The Ubuntu 14.04 version is OK → libdrm-dev (2.4.67-1ubuntu0.14.04.2 and others) [security] ... https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libdrm-dev ... ... Your errors : Please remove 'xenial' entries from `/etc/apt/{sources.list, sources.list.d/**}`

Comment: @KnudLarsen Thanks for patience now I'm trying to solve it from /etc/apt/{sources.list, sources.list.d/**} but it's a big mess, full of lines. There is another solution? Also cause my fear it's to delete other important lines. Are you sure that I can delete all the lines which contains the word xenial?

Comment: You can comment out all suspicious lines with a hash mark ( # ). Then they are easily recreated. Or you can move the current files to (new) backup folders : /etc/apt/{ **back/,  sources.list.d/back/** }, to have only the relevant file(s) : https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this?